Small bugs with a lightweight xcoffins-based mdframed alternative
I've recently tried to add page-break support to a lightweight xcoffins-based mdframes alternative I've made that started off with Put an xcoffin around an environment's content
It essentially works like so:
\defsimplebox{examplebox}{FF5733}{Some Label}

\begin{examplebox}
Some content
\end{examplebox}

produces

I've tried to make a \vsplit-based page-breakable version, and after much trial and error it seems to be working! ...mostly. There are a few niggles I'd really appreciate help with:

Having it preserve baseline alignment across columns only works with \vspace{-0.08em} % Why on earth is this needed for baseline alignment!?, I feel like this is a strange hack that shouldn't be needed
Columns aren't always the same height
Vertically alignment isn't right without \setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
Across columns, text baselines are no longer aligned

Demo of the a-bit-off column height difference:

Demo of the off baseline alignment being off with a split simplebox

Unfortunately at this point I've reached the end of what I think I can accomplish by myself.
Code
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{xcoffins}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewCoffin\SBXBaseline
\NewCoffin\SBXHeader
\NewCoffin\SBXContent
\NewCoffin\SBXSideRule
\newbox\SBXSplitBox
\cs_new_protected:Nn \simplebox_start:nnn {
  % #1 ding, #3 name, #4 label
  \vcoffin_set:Nnn \SBXHeader { \linewidth - 1em } {
    \noindent\textcolor{#2}{#1}~\textcolor{#2}{\textbf{#3}}}
  \vcoffin_set:Nnw \SBXContent { \linewidth - 1.5em }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \simplebox_split_content:n {
  % #1 name
  \setbox\SBXSplitBox = \vbox:n { \vbox_unpack_drop:N \SBXContent }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { \dim_eval:n { \dim_min:nn { \pagegoal } { \textheight } - \pagetotal - 2\baselineskip } }
  \setbox0 = \vsplit\SBXSplitBox to \l_tmpa_dim
  \vcoffin_set:Nnn \SBXContent { \CoffinWidth \SBXContent } { \box0 %
    \vspace{-1.7\baselineskip}
    \noindent\textcolor{#1}{\textbf{\ldots }}
    \vspace*{-0.3\baselineskip}}
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \simplebox_split_refill:nnnn {
  % #1 ding, #2 ding offset, #3 name, #4 label
  \simplebox_start:nnn {#1} {#3} {#4,\space{}\emph{continued}}
  \vspace*{-0.2\baselineskip}
  \vbox_unpack_drop:N \SBXSplitBox
  \vcoffin_set_end:
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \simplebox_typeset:nn {
    % #1 name, #2 ding offset
    \vcoffin_set:Nnn \SBXBaseline {0pt} {\vbox{}}
    \SetHorizontalCoffin\SBXSideRule{\color{#1}\rule{1pt}{\dim_eval:n { \CoffinTotalHeight\SBXContent + \baselineskip }}}
    \JoinCoffins*\SBXContent[l,t]\SBXSideRule[l,t](\dim_eval:n {#2 - 1em}, \dim_eval:n{\baselineskip - 0.5em})
    \JoinCoffins*\SBXContent[l,t]\SBXHeader[l,B](-1em, 0.5\baselineskip)
    \JoinCoffins*\SBXBaseline[l,T]\SBXContent[l,T]
    \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
    \noindent\TypesetCoffin\SBXBaseline(\dim_eval:n { 1em - #2 + 1pt }, 0pt)
    \vspace*{\CoffinTotalHeight\SBXContent}
    \vspace{-0.08em} % Why on earth is this needed for baseline alignment!?
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \simplebox_break_typeset:nnnn {
    % #1 ding, #2 ding offset, #3 name, #4 label
    \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim {\dim_eval:n { \CoffinTotalHeight\SBXContent + \baselineskip }}
    \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpb_dim { \dim_eval:n { \dim_min:nn { \pagegoal } { \textheight } - \pagetotal - \baselineskip } }
    \dim_compare:nNnTF {\l_tmpa_dim} > {\l_tmpb_dim} {
      \simplebox_split_content:n {#3}
      \simplebox_typeset:nn {#3} {#2}
      \newpage
      \simplebox_split_refill:nnnn {#1} {#2} {#3} {#4}
      \simplebox_break_typeset:nnnn {#1} {#2} {#3} {#4}
    }{%
      \simplebox_typeset:nn {#3} {#2}
    }
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\defsimplebox}{O{\ding{117}} O{0.35em} O{#1} O{#2} m m m}{
  % #1 ding, #2 ding offset, #3 alt-ding, #4 alt-ding offset,
  % #5 name, #6 colour, #7 default label
  \definecolor{#5}{HTML}{#6}
  \NewDocumentEnvironment{#5}{ O{#7} }{
    \simplebox_start:nnn {#1} {#5} {##1}
  }{
    \vcoffin_set_end:
    \simplebox_break_typeset:nnnn {#3} {#4} {#5} {##1}
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\defsimplebox{examplebox}{FF5733}{Some Label}

\begin{document}

Hello, see how the length of the first column doesn't match the second :(

\begin{examplebox}
Some content
\end{examplebox}

\end{document}

